# UITableView inside of UIViewController not responding (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have implemented a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`. I have created a custom class of `UITableView` named `HomePageTableView`, and referenced that in the storyboard. Below is the code for `HomePageTableView` and `HomePageViewController`

HomePageViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var tableView: HomePageTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

HomePageTableView:

```
class HomePageTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var items: [String] = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
```

When I try to run this, the tableview loads an empty tableview, and no cells can be selected or show any content. I cannot select any cells or interact with the tableview at all. I was wondering how I could load data into this tableview and configure it so that I could interact with it. I considered placing the tableview code into the view controller, but it would be more useful to have the tableview in its own class.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: tableView.datasource = tableView

Comment: Where would I add this? HomePageTableView has no member datasource

Comment: Datasource code neither belongs in a view controller class, nor view class. It belongs in it's own class.

Comment: Right now I am just putting the data into an array in HomePageTableView for simplicity. I downloaded a project that implemented everything inside of a UIViewController, and it worked fine. It just doesn't work when I remove the tableview code and place it into its own UITableView file. I remember that this was how you did it in Obj-c though

Comment: @SulaimanMajeed, how does this simplify anything? tableviews are meant to be used in a composition over inheritance fashion, not to be subclassed. Not in Objective-C, not in Swift. in 7 years of iOS development I didn't ran across a singe use case where subclassing UITableView would had be the right choice. And implementing this in the ViewController is just a bad habit that doesnt die as it is thoughtlessly copied by unexperienced developers over and over again.

Comment: What do you suggest the best way to implement a table view inside of a view controller is?

Comment: We shouldn't implement it inside of the UIViewController or subclass it...

Comment: @SulaimanMajeed, did you read my comments? Neither in the view controller, nor in the view.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this. I think it should work if all the connections are okay.

```
class HomePageViewController: HomePageTableView {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
     }

}
```

Comment: HomePageViewController is a UIViewController, not a HomePageTableView. It only contains and controls the HomePageTableView

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Okay what about this you create an instance of your tableview in HomePageTableView. Then create a function which simply do tableview.reload(). Then inherit this class along with UIViewController in HomePageViewController and simply call that function.